TimeOfDay.now() returning "instance of 'Timeofday'" instead of current time
I'm working on a application which asks a time from user, i have implemented an action button which shows Timepicker dialog when pressed,everything works fine when it's run as a debug application but when i run it as a release version it returns "instance of 'Timeofday'" instead of current time.Code snippet of the action button :
class timeselection extends StatefulWidget {
  const timeselection({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<timeselection> createState() => _timeselectionState();
}

class _timeselectionState extends State<timeselection> {
  // TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
  String finaltime = time;
  Future<void> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final TimeOfDay? picked_s = await showTimePicker(
          context: context,
          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
          confirmText: 'You sure?',
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return MediaQuery(
              data:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
              child: child!,
            );
          });
      if (picked_s != null) {
        setState(() {
          //   selectedTime = picked_s;
          finaltime = picked_s.toString(); //.replaceAll(r"TimeOfDay(", r"");
          //finaltime = finaltime.replaceAll(r")", r"");
          time = finaltime;
        });
        showDialog<String>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Selected time'),
            content: Text(TimeOfDay.now().toString()),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                child: const Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Time Selection error'),
          content: Text(e.toString()),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ActionChip(
      label: Text(
        time,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      // padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      onPressed: () async {
        await _selectTime(context);
      },
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF002021),
      avatar: const CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF002021),
        foregroundColor: const Color(0xFF002021),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.schedule_outlined,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

here time is a string which is not null and may contain a time or "Select a time.".
image:


To format a TimeOfDay object, you need to use its format method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay/format.html
